# Order By with Case Statements Not Working as Expected

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I'm trying to sort a report in the order that the end user wants to work it.

First, it should be sorted by the following scenarios:

1. String_Field is populated, but Comment_Date is null
2. String_Field is not populated
3. Both String_Field and Comment_Date are populated

And then it should be sorted by the aging of Task_Date.

I've added the following to my ORDER BY:

```
(case when max(table1.comment_date) is null then 2 else 1 end) DESC,
(case when table1.string_field is null then 2 else 1 end) ASC,
max(table2.task_date) ASC
```

And then I added them to my SELECT also:

```
(case when max(table1.comment_date) is null then 2 else 1 end) as sort1
(case when table1.string_field is null then 2 else 1 end) as sort2
max(table2.task_date) as task_date
```

What I'm getting, and cannot figure out for the life of me why, is this (edited to show the high/low at each change):

[image: Picture of Sample Results]

I've tried casting, moving the aggregation around, and adding the values together, and I still end up with those 2s stuck in the middle of some invisible split in the 1s.

If it makes any difference, I come up with the values for string_field via a CTE Union Query, and comment_date is joined to string_field in a second CTE, before the second CTE (table1) is left joined to the table that contains task_date (table2). You can have a string_field without a comment_date, but never a comment_date without a string_field. There must be a task_date for the entry to appear in the report. The report is grouped by string_field.

I'm on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

Edited to add Quasi-SQL:

```
WITH 
old_new_string AS (
    SELECT
    tablea.old_string_field,
    tablea.string_field,
    'A' as match_type
    FROM
    tablea
    WHERE
    tablea.old_string_field is not null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    B1.string_field AS old_string_field,
    B2.string_field AS string_field,
    'B1' as match_type
    FROM
    tableb B1
    INNER JOIN tableb B2 ON B1.string_field <> B2.string_field AND B1.id1 = B2.id1
    WHERE
    B1.id1 is not null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    B1.string_field AS old_string_field,
    B2.string_field AS string_field,
    'B2' as match_type
    FROM
    tableb B1
    INNER JOIN tableb B2 ON B1.string_field <> B2.string_field AND B1.id1 = B2.id2
    WHERE
    B1.id1 is not null),
table1 AS (
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT /* Enables order by to improve join performance */
    old_new_string.old_string_field,
    old_new_string.string_field,
    old_new_string.match_type,
    comment_date = (SELECT max(comment_table.comment_date) FROM comment_table WHERE old_new_string.string_field = comment_table.string_field and comment_table.comment_code = '001')
    FROM
    old_new_string
    ORDER BY
    old_new_string.old_string_field)
SELECT
tablez.string_field as old_string_field, 
max(table2.task_date) as task_date, 
min(cast(getdate() - table2.task_date as bigint)) as Aging
table1.string_field as new_string_field, 
max(table1.match_type) as match_type, 
max(table1.comment_date) as comment_date, 
sort_order1 = (case when max(table1.comment_date) is null then 2 else 1 end), 
sort_order2 = (case when table1.string_field is null then 2 else 1 end) 
FROM 
tablez 
INNER JOIN table2 ON tablez.string_field = table2.string_field 
LEFT JOIN table1 on tablez.string_field = table1.old_string_field
Where 
table2.task_date IS NOT NULL
Group By 
tablez.string_field, table1.new_string_field  
ORDER BY 
(case when max(table1.comment_date) is null then 2 else 1 end) DESC,
(case when table1.string_field is null then 2 else 1 end) ASC,
max(table2.task_date) ASC
```

Comment: Do you really want us to figure this all out? Adding your code would really help a lot... And some sample data and expected output also.

Comment: I'm more looking for pointers - for example, I didn't think a join could impact an ORDER BY - is that wrong? Is there some esoteric issue with using case statements within an order by? Or could the aggregation be impacting?

Comment: The data I'm working with is highly sensitive - I wouldn't even want to post the SQL for security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY 
  case when max(table1.comment_date) is null then 2 else 0 end 
+ case when table1.string_field is null then 0 else 1 end DESC
```

or

```
ORDER BY CASE
   WHEN max(table1.comment_date) is null and table1.string_field is not null 
      THEN 0
   WHEN table1.string_field is null 
      THEN 1
   WHEN max(table1.comment_date) is not null and table1.string_field is not null 
      THEN 2
      ELSE 3 END
```

Comment: Thanks, but same behavior with both! :(

Comment: I suspect `max(table1.comment_date)` is NULL much more often than you think... perhaps for pretty much every record. If **any** `table1.comment_date` value in a group is `null`, then then full `max(table1.comment_date)`  for that row/group will be `null`. The result is all the records have the same precedence in the ORDER BY clause, and within that precedence Sql Server is free to use whatever natural clustering order came out of the query.

Comment: If that was the case, it would resolve as null consistently, right? And I would see that reflected in my sort1 field? I've edited my original post to show the full SQL - I changed the table/field names and removed a lot of extra fields/joins.

Comment: I cut my original query down to match the sample - took out all the extra fields and joins, and it sorts correctly. Yet I can't find anything online about how a join might interfere with an order by? I thought as long as the ORDER BY was on the outermost query, it would basically flatten the results before sorting them.